# Menu css style not working

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, drop-down-menu

I'm making a menu for my website. I want to make it responsive so using bootstrap to collapse it and to show only logo/project title.

I tried to add class "collapse" or "navbar-collapse" but no effect. I can't even add a dropdown inside the menu, I don't know why is happening this? Can somebody help me:
Here is my js fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/egzontina/qj17hrhu/5/#&togetherjs=fORQnPjH95)

My html code:

```
<div id='cssmenu'>   
    <ul>
        <li id="logo"><a class="project-name-align"href="#">#MyProject</a></li>
        <li class='active'><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Products</span></a></li>
        <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
        <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My css code:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700);
#cssmenu {
  background: #000000;
  width: auto;
  padding-top:20px;
  height:80px;
  text-align:right;
  padding-right:10px;
}

.project-name-align{
  text-align:left !important;
} 
#logo a:hover{
  color: #d94939 !important;
}

#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  zoom: 1;
}

#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#cssmenu.align-right ul li {
  float: right;
}

#cssmenu.align-center ul {
  text-align: center;
}

#cssmenu ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: color .25s;
  -moz-transition: color .25s;
  -ms-transition: color .25s;
  -o-transition: color .25s;
  transition: color .25s;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:hover {
  color: #d94939;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  right: -3px;
  top: 19px;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  background: #ffffff;
  opacity: .5;
}

#cssmenu ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0;
  background: #d94939;
  -webkit-transition: width .25s;
  -moz-transition: width .25s;
  -ms-transition: width .25s;
  -o-transition: width .25s;
  transition: width .25s;
}

#cssmenu ul li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu ul li:last-child > a:after {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #d94939;
}

#cssmenu ul li.active a:before {
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu.align-right li.last > a:after,
#cssmenu.align-right li:last-child > a:after {
  display: block;
}

#cssmenu.align-right li:first-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: If you're using bootstrap i'd look in the devtools to see which styles actually get applied, it might be that `collapsed` is implemented as `.navbar.collapsed` in which case you'd need to use bootstraps `navbar` class or create your own collapse class instead

Comment: @SidneyLiebrand but I'm using my custom style, if u  can check my jsfiddle

Comment: You're supposed to overwrite bootstrap defaults with custom styling to give your website the feel you want it to have instead of the bootstrap feel, you're not supplying any bootstrap class but are just expecting something to work, I think bootstrap docs will hold more info on what you can and cannot do when using the collapsed class (I'm commenting as I'm no expert on bootstrap, just trying to point you in the right direction which usually are the docs of the framework you're using)